# How to use refactoring method with functions on python code?

Tags: python, pandas, refactoring

I am in the learning phase of writing python code's. I have created the below code and have got results successfully however, i have been asked to refactor the code and i am not very sure how to proceed. I did refer to multiple post related to refactoring but got more confused and was not clear how its done. Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks.

````
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',100)
data = pd.read_excel (r'S:\folder\file1.xlsx')
df_mail =pd.DataFrame(data,columns= ['CustomerName','CDAAccount','Transit'])
print(df_mail)
df_maillist =df_mail.rename(columns={'CDAAccount':'ACOUNT_NUM','Transit':'BRANCH_NUM'})
print(df_maillist)

## 1) Read SAS files 
pathcifbas = 'S:\folder\custbas.sas7bdat'
pathcifadr = 'S:\folder\cusadr.sas7bdat'
pathcifacc = 'S:\folder\cusact.sas7bdat'

##custbas.sas7bdat 

columns=['CIFNUM','CUSTOMR_LANGUG_C']
dfcifbas = pd.read_sas(pathcifbas)
print(dfcifbas.head())
df_langprf= dfcifbas[columns]
print(df_langprf.head())
df_lang =df_langprf.rename(columns={'CUSTOMR_LANGUG_C':'Language Preference'})
print(df_lang)

## cusadr.sas7bdat

dfcifadr = pd.read_sas(pathcifadr)
print(dfcifadr.head())
cols=['CIFNUM','ADRES_STREET_NUM','ADRES_STREET_NAME','ADRES_CITY','ADRES_STATE_PROV_C','FULL_POSTAL','ADRES_COUNTRY_C','ADRES_SPECL_ADRES']
df_adr= dfcifadr[cols]
print(df_adr.head)

### Renaming the columns
df_adrress =df_adr.rename(columns={'ADRES_CITY':'City','ADRES_STATE_PROV_C':'Province','FULL_POSTAL':'Postal Code','ADRES_COUNTRY_C':'Country','ADRES_SPECL_ADRES':'Special Address'})
print(df_adrress)

## cusact.sas7bdat

dfcifacc = pd.read_sas(pathcifacc)
print(dfcifacc.head())
colmns=['CIFNUM','ACOUNT_NUM','BRANCH_NUM','APLICTN_ID']
df_acc= dfcifacc[colmns]
print(df_acc)
## Filtering the tables with ['APLICTN_ID']== b'CDA'
df_cda= df_acc['APLICTN_ID']== b'CDA'
print(df_cda.head())
df_acccda = df_acc[df_cda]
print(df_acccda)

## Joining dataframes (df_lang), (df_adrress) and (df_acccda) on CIF_NUM
from functools import reduce
Combine_CIFNUM= [df_acccda,df_lang,df_adrress ]
df_cifnum = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='CIFNUM'), Combine_CIFNUM)
print(df_cifnum)

#convert multiple columns object byte to string

df_cifnumstr= df_cifnum.select_dtypes([np.object])
df_cifnumstr=df_cifnumstr.stack().str.decode('latin1').unstack()
for col in df_cifnumstr:
   df_cifnum[col] = df_cifnumstr[col]
print(df_cifnum) ## Combined Data Frame

# Joining Mail list with df_cifnum(combined dataframe)

Join1_mailcifnum=pd.merge(df_maillist,df_cifnum, on=['ACOUNT_NUM','BRANCH_NUM'],how='left')
print(Join1_mailcifnum)

## dropping unwanted columns

Com_maillist= Join1_mailcifnum.drop(['CIFNUM','APLICTN_ID'], axis =1)
print(Com_maillist)

## concatenating Street Num + Street Name = Street Address

Com_maillist["Street Address"]=(Com_maillist['ADRES_STREET_NUM'].map(str)+ ' ' + Com_maillist['ADRES_STREET_NAME'].map(str))
print (Com_maillist.head())

## Rearranging columns

Final_maillist= Com_maillist[["CustomerName","ACOUNT_NUM","BRANCH_NUM","Street Address","City","Province","Postal Code","Country","Language Preference","Special Address"]]
print(Final_maillist)

## Export to excel

Final_maillist.to_excel(r'S:\Data Analysis\folder\Final_List.xlsx',index= False, sheet_name='Final_Maillist',header=True)```
````

Comment: "refactoring" just means changing the code.  Did they give you any hints about what needs to change?

Comment: they just said to refactor the code into functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good code refactoring can be composed of many different steps, and depending on what your educator/client/manager/etc. expects, could involve vastly different amounts of effort and time spent. It's a good idea to ask this person what expectations they have for this specific project and start there.

However, for someone relatively new to Python I'd recommend you start with readability and organization. Make sure all your variable names are explicit and readable (assuming you're not using a required pattern like Hungarian notation). As a starting point, the Python naming conventions tend to use lowercase letters and underscores, with exceptions for certain objects or class names. Python actually has a really in-depth style guide called PEP-8. You can find it here

> https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

A personal favorite of mine are comments. Comments should always contain the "why" of something, not necessarily the "how" (your code should be readable enough to make this part relatively obvious). This is a bit harder for smaller scripts or assignments where you don't have a ton of individual choice, but it's good to keep in mind.

If you've learned about object oriented programming, you should definitely split up tasks into functions and classes. In your specific case, you could create individual functions for things like loading files, performing specific operations on the file contents, and exporting. If you notice a bunch of functions that tend to have similar themes, that may be a good time to look into creating a class for those functions!

Finally, and again this is a personal preference (for basic scripts anyways), but I like to see a main declaration for readability and organization.

```
# imports go here!

# specific functions
def some_function():
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # the start of your program goes here!
```

This is all pretty heavily simplified for the purposes of just starting out. There are plenty of other resources that can go more in depth in organization, good practices, and optimization.

Best of luck!